# how do i delete a photo from a hangouts conversation

Tags: google-hangouts

i sent a picture using Hangouts.  I don't want the picture in the conversation thread.  how do i delete just that picture, but leave all the other texts in the thread?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Google Hangouts is no longer available](https://support.google.com/chat/answer/9854901).

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the hangout should block people from seeing your photo, even if you are added back. However, the other participants of the chat will be able to see you have posted a photo, it will just be blanked out.